# How does using a function as a parameter for an IF statement work in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code from a tutorial however even after looking at a couple of tutorials I can't completely understand the exact workings of it despite it being extremely basic.

```
  if(mysql_num_rows($result)) { 
    while($term = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
      $terms[] = array('term'=>$term);    
    }
  }
```

I can't get my head behind what the IF statement is actually testing here. I know that the MySQL_num_rows function is counting the number of rows returned by my database query and returns an integer (in the case of this query there is only a single row), but what does that mean for the IF statement. I'm assuming it's testing to make sure that it is not null, is this correct? Even if it is what is the exact logic behind this.

Sorry for the beginners question, just starting out.

Comment: Step one would be finding a newer tutorial, one that doesn't tell you to use deprecated functions.

Comment: [`if`](http://php.net/if) does not have *parameters*, it evaluates *expressions*. And all function calls happen to be that, [expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php). (Other languages, btw, have "procedures", which unlike functions can just be used as statement. In PHP all functions are functions, regardless of any return value.)

Comment: Step two would be looking at the manual page for [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php). Look at the return values and it should become clear what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on newer functions and I will look at that, as for the manual page, I had looked at that but interpreted some of what it said incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `if` statement, the value is converted to a boolean before it checks.

So, `mysql_num_rows` returns a number.  If it's `0`, it gets converted to `false`, and `1` (or higher) becomes `true`.  Then the `if` runs or not depending on the boolean conversion.

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Every other value is considered `TRUE` (including any resource).

Comment: Thanks Rocket, this explained it perfectly. It is what I thought was going on but wanted to check to make sure I was understanding the basics correctly.

Comment: @James: PHP's type juggling means that it does things like this, which may not be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It's testing to know if there are results. If no results are returned, the value will be 0 which evaluates to false, the loop will therefore be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This function `mysql_num_rows($result)` returns the number of selected rows which is translated to TRUE if there are more than 0 otherwise 0 -> FALSE

Answer (score 0):

PHP is very loose in how it interprets if statements, it is testing to see if the function has returned anything at all or if it is either true (anything instanciated counts as true so if it has returned any rows at all it counts as true), false (i.e. not instanciated has returned 0 or an error) or null/none (basically the same as false).

Comment: `mysql_num_rows()` shouldn't return `null`.

Comment: no I meant thats what if is trying to equate the function to whatever that function may be - either true or false/null

Comment: False and null aren't equivalent; and `mysql_num_rows()` never returns `null` anyways, so adding it to the answer just creates more confusion.

Comment: No they aren't equivilant i didn't mean that I can see how it looks like that though! What I meant is IF looks for true or false and null counts as false - from php manual on boolean:               When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
    * the boolean FALSE itself
    * the integer 0 (zero)
    * the float 0.0 (zero)
    * the empty string, and the string "0"
    * an array with zero elements
    * the special type NULL (including unset variables)
    * SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

*** Every other value is considered TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

IN each sequence of this loop , it fetches the record which the pointer , points to it . and then the pointer goes to the next record. But if there is no record (at the end), the `$term` array will be empty which is equivalent to the boolean value `FALSE`

take a look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

so the while loop stops at this point.